# Externalising values from "ibm-web-bnd.xml"

Tags: websphere-7

I'm using websphere application server 7, then I want to externalise values from "ibm-web-bnd.xml", because my application must turn on 3 environments.

```
<virtual-host name="default_host"/>
<ejb-ref name="ejb/EjbFacade" binding-name="corbaname::localhost:2809#cell/nodes/businessNode01/servers/server1/ejb/EjbFacade"/>
```

Thank's in advance !

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find a good way.

Comment: I found a solution but it doesn't work ...
I added a websphere variable then I call it using ${EJB_FACADE}

    <ejb-ref name="ejb/EjbFacade" binding-name="${EJB_FACADE}"/>

Any help please !